# C array declaration with inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly, esp-idf

I recently came upon this snippet:

```
extern const uint8_t server_root_cert_pem_start[] asm("_binary_server_root_cert_pem_start");
//                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ what's going on here?
```

in the [esp-idf examples](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/protocols/https_mbedtls/main/https_mbedtls_example_main.c)(line 74). I cannot understand the declaration, and my online search hasn't been successful. My best guess would be that this code:

- Uses `uint8_t` as a replacement for `char` since they have the same size (1 byte). No clue why though
- Ultimately declares a string (a `const char` array) <s>by inferring the array size from the string length</s> whose length has been specified outside our module

Even if my assumptions are correct, I fail to understand **why** it's written this way or what happens with "null termination" in this case. So the actual questions:

- What is this code doing?
- Why is it doing it this way (advantages)?
- Are there any implications that differentiate it from a simple C-style declaration?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels

Answer (score 1):

This is compiler dependend. However my guess is that this code declare an array named server_root_cert_pem_start and binds it to another symbol (memory location) _binary_server_root_cert_pem_start probably defined elsewhere (in an assembly file?)

Comment: Yes, this is GNU C syntax to set the asm symbol name for a variable, e.g. to hard-code the leading `_`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html